# How do grab the name of an mp4 when using urllib?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, urllib

The link.txt file contains links that I'm looping thru. The links lead to pages that have mp4 files. I am downloading these. It works fine except I cannot grab the original name of the mp4.

Current output for the mp4 file:

```
videoname.mp4
```

Desired output for the mp4 file:

```
V14728_full_h264_1500.mp4
```

My Code:

```
one = open("link.txt", "r")
for two in one.readlines():
    driver.get(two)
    sleep(2)
    vid = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "video")
    src = vid.get_attribute("src")
    driver.get(src)
    sleep(2)
    url = driver.current_url
    print(url)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'videoname.mp4') #NEED FIX HERE
```

HTML of the page:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <input type="hidden" id="_w_tusk">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome-extension://dbjbempljhcmhlfpfacalomonjpalpko/scripts/inspector.js">
      </script><script src="chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/prompt.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body class="vsc-initialized" style="">
      <div class="vsc-controller">      
      </div><video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
         <source src="https://download2.[REDACTED].com/7eefd14b306c441ba17f2bd72e371586/61cfc9a7/stream/V14728/V14728_vids/V14728_full_h264_1500.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video><span id="copylAddress" style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: -9999em;">
      </span>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot of the HTML]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the name of the file simply split the url by `/` and pick the last element from the list:

```
src="https://download2.[REDACTED].com/7eefd14b306c441ba17f2bd72e371586/61cfc9a7/stream/V14728/V14728_vids/V14728_full_h264_1500.mp4"

src.split('/')[-1]
```

Output:

```
V14728_full_h264_1500.mp4
```

In your example:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, src.split('/')[-1])
```

Comment: THANK YOU. Instead of: "src" it should be "url" but otherwise perfect answer.

Comment: Happy to help - Just a question is not the `src` equal to the `url`?  In this case it do not need to perform `url = driver.current_url`

Comment: src does not equal url. Apparently it's like a hyperlink(?) situation. Typing in the src leads to a different url.